# Javascript - Bind to elements behind another element?

Tags: javascript, bind

Say I have two divs:

```
<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

And say that both `divs` have the same width & height and are on top of each other, with `#container2` being on top of the other (i.e. the `z-index` of `#container2` is higher).

Is there absolutely anyway to have your mouse binded to the element underneath (`#container1`)?

I am asking this because in my situation, `#container2` partially blocks portions of `#container1`; so where there is no overlap, I have no problem with binding, but when there are overlapping, then I cannot bind

EDIT
Specifically, `#container1` is the timeline, and `#container2` is a specific task that starts say from 9:00am until 12:00am. I want to be able to drag the task to a different time. So I want to bind to the timeline (`#container1`).

Comment: They're always above one another? Could you just bind the mouse events to `container2` but have the function manipulate `container1`?

Comment: please read my edit on the main post

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `pointer-events:none` to the element.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6TfJn/) - try highlighting the text, you can go through the element.

```
#container2 {
    z-index:2;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Just take the [property's support](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) into consideration.

Comment: Problem is that I need to be able to drag `#container2`. So if I add that property, then I can never grab it. I tried to have another class where I would add it to the element upon `dragstart`. This works in Firefox, but not in chrome

Answer (score 0):

on the div that is over the other use

```
css
    #a{
        pointer-events:none;
    }



<div id='a'>on top</div>
<div id='b'>under</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jre5s/)